# When can an unknown integral be written as an ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I am hoping to numerically solve for the unknown function $I(t)$
\begin{align}
I(t) = \int_0^tf(x,t)\,dx
\end{align}
by converting it into one or more ODEs.  The function $f(x,t)$ is known.  If $f$ were only a function of one variable, then we trivially have
\begin{align}
\frac{dI}{dt} = f(t).
\end{align}
If $f(x,t) = g(x)h(t)$ is separable, then we can also succeed, but in general Leibniz's integral rule leads to complications.

Need $f$ be separable to convert its integral into an ODE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the present case,
$$
I'(t)=f(t,t)+\int_0^t\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)\,\mathrm dx.
$$

Comment: Certainly true, but I am aiming to remove all integral operators so as to obtain a pure ODE.

Comment: No reason to expect $I$ solves an ODE in general.

Comment: Is it possible to prove, based on a given $f$, that $I$ does not satisfy an ODE?

Comment: Define "does not satisfy an ODE". Of course $I$ satisfy the ODE $I'=g$ for some well-chosen $g$ (namely, $g=I'$...). But I would not expect a general procedure allowing to find, based on $f$ only, some $(g,h)$, say, such that $I'(t)+g(t)I(t)=h(t)$. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks Did.  If ever such a procedure turns up, let me know.